# What is the process for a Japanese citizen to inherit an IRA?

Tags: united-states, ira, japan

A Japanese citizen is a primary beneficiary of my IRA. What is the process for her to inherit my IRA?

Answer (score 2):

She needs to contact the trustee (the company that manages the IRA) and provide them whatever the information they require. Probably your death certificate and her tax ID (if she doesn't have US SSN - then her ITIN). Check with the IRA management company for details.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @littleadv's answer, if the the beneficiary has no US citizenship or residency, she/he will be subject to pay a tax treaty rate when reciving the inheritance. The inheritance source plays an important factor as there are some exceptions.

If Japan has no treaty with the US, the beneficiary is subject the 30% income tax.

Reference [IRS Pub 519](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Publication-519,-U.S.-Tax-Guide-for-Aliens-1).